# Density estimation for big feature space

Tags: confidence-interval, density-estimation

let's say I have a data set with 100 features and a couple million of samples. Whenever I get a new sample, I would like to estimate how many samples would have been around it in the original set (let's say within L1 distance of $\varepsilon$).  How can I do this in an efficient way? To me it sounds like I would like to estimate (joint) density function at a particular point. Perhaps, there's a way to train a neural net that outputs such density function based on the features values.

Motivation: I would like to use this density function value at a particular point in order to understand how confident should I be in my prediction at that point (the higher the density, the higher would my confidence be).

Comment: Check [FLANN](https://github.com/mariusmuja/flann). It will directly provide how many sample will be "approximately" close to a query point. In general, you might want to check the notion of [approximate nearest neighbor search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(1%2B%CE%B5)-approximate_nearest_neighbor_search).

Comment: @usεr11852 thanks! looks like something useful

Answer (score 0):

one of the idea is to have a lot of clusters let's say 10000, run KNN on all training observations and this will provide "tree search" in your samples

then when you will have new observation take several let's say 5 nearest clusters and only process points in these clusters